# A problem on efficient coding.

Tags: information-theory, entropy

The following example, although somewhat unrealistic, is a case in which exact matching to a noisy channel
is possible. There are two channel symbols, 0 and 1, and the noise affects them in blocks of seven symbols.
A block of seven is either transmitted without error, or exactly one symbol of the seven is incorrect. These
eight possibilities are equally likely. Thus we have

\begin{align}
C(\text{capacity})&=\max(H(y)-H_x(y))\\
&=\frac{1}{7}\left(7+\frac{8}{8}\log_2\frac{1}{8}\right)
\end{align}
I didn't understand the solution. What I can observe is that the  'Transmission Possibilities':

1. 0000000   (No errors)
2. 1000000   (1st symbol error)
3. 0100000   (2nd symbol error)
4. 0010000   (3rd symbol error)
5. 0001000   (4th symbol error)
6. 0000100   (5th symbol error)
7. 0000010   (6th symbol error)
8. 0000001   (7th symbol error)

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
H(Y|X) &= -\sum_{i=1}^{2} \sum_{j=1}^{8} P(x_i, y_j) \cdot \log_2(P(y_j|x_i)) \\
&= -\left(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{8} \frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{8} \frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8}\right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{8} \frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{8} \frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8} \\
&= -4 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8}\right) - 4 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8}\right) \\
&= -8 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{8} \log_2\frac{1}{8}\right) \\
&= -\log_2 \frac{1}{8} \\
&= 3 \text{ bit}
\end{align*}
Can someone explain the rest of the part of solution. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: What's $C{}{}$?

Comment: Here $C$ is Capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X^n$ and $Y^n$ denote the input and output blocks of length $n=7$. Consider them as macro-symbols, which correspond to the inputs and output of our channel. In this setting

$$I(X^n;Y^n)=H(Y^n)-H(Y^n|X^n)$$

with $H(Y^n|X^n)=H(X^n+Z^n|X^n)=H(Z^n|X^n)=H(Z^n)=3$ bits, where $Z^n$ is the error pattern.

Hence $H(Y^n|X^n)$ does not depend on the input distribution, and we are left with maximizing $H(Y^n)$. We have the bound $H(Y^n) \le 7$ which corresponds to a uniform distribution for $Y^n$. The question is if there is an input distribution that gives that output distribution. And there is: a uniform input. Because the output $Y^n=X^n+Z^n$ implies $X^n=Y^n+Z^n$, and for each output are eight possible inputs and pattern errors.

Hence $C = \max I(X^n;Y^n) = 7 - 3 = 4$ bits.

In this (very) particular case we can assert that this is correct by finding an ideal coding: use the 16 codewords from a Hamming $(7,4)$ code (which can correct up to 1 error). In this way, you can trasmit 4 bits of information in each block without error.

Now, the above is the capacity of the "block" channel: $4$ bits per $n-$block. To get the capacity of the original channel we need to divide by $7$.
Hence we get $C = 4/7$ bits per channel use (binary transmission).